# Exclude Blazor pages from code coverage via .runsettings

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, code-coverage, coverlet

I have [this](https://github.com/mu88/RaspiFanController/) little Blazor application. Now I'd like to exclude all Blazor pages from code coverage via `.runsettings`. The pages are located under `/RaspiFanController/Pages/`. My tests are using NUnit and the coverage calculation uses coverlet.

I've already tried to create the file `/Tests/.runsettings` with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        <Functions>
                            <Exclude>
                                <Function>.*Pages.*</Function>
                            </Exclude>
                        </Functions>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Unfortunately, the code coverage still contains the Blazor pages - both within JetBrains Rider and via `dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`.

Edit: I'm not bound to solve this via `.runsettings`. If it is possible via `csproj` I'm also fine

Answer (score 0):

The `.runsettings` file has to look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat code coverage">
                <Configuration>
                    <ExcludeByFile>**/*.razor,</ExcludeByFile>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

In my case I had to pass this file explicitly to `dotnet test`, so the command looks like this:
`dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --no-restore --settings coverlet.runsettings`

Unfortunately, JetBrains Rider/dotCover does not honor these settings when calculating the code coverage.